# How to handle namespace declarations in child Elements for XPath in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml, namespaces

I'm trying to use XPath and XML as specified in [MDN: Introduction to using XPath in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript). However, when I tried to use my XML as is, it resulted in an error (see below)

```js
const xmlStr = `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:n0="http://tempuri.org/">
    <soapenv:Header>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <n0:SavePartnerDetailsWithToken xmlns:n2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
            <n0:userToken></n0:userToken>
            <n2:myNode>valueHere</n2:myNode>
        </n0:SavePartnerDetailsWithToken>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`;
const xmlObj = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlStr, 'application/xml');
const nsResolver = xmlObj.createNSResolver(xmlObj.ownerDocument === null ? xmlObj.documentElement : xmlObj.ownerDocument.documentElement);
firstNode = xmlObj.evaluate('/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/n0:SavePartnerDetailsWithToken/n2:myNode', xmlObj, nsResolver, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
console.log(firstNode.singleNodeValue.textContent)
```

I then moved all the xmlns: attributes to the root, since the createNSResolver() method expects the documentElement as a parameter.

```js
const xmlStr = `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:n0="http://tempuri.org/"
    xmlns:n2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <soapenv:Header>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <n0:SavePartnerDetailsWithToken>
            <n0:userToken></n0:userToken>
            <n2:myNode>valueHere</n2:myNode>
        </n0:SavePartnerDetailsWithToken>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`;
const xmlObj = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlStr, 'application/xml');
const nsResolver = xmlObj.createNSResolver(xmlObj.ownerDocument === null ? xmlObj.documentElement : xmlObj.ownerDocument.documentElement);
firstNode = xmlObj.evaluate('/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/n0:SavePartnerDetailsWithToken/n2:myNode', xmlObj, nsResolver, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
console.log(firstNode.singleNodeValue.textContent)
```

This works. However, I cannot ensure that the namespace declarations being on the root element for the XML that is uploaded to my application at runtime. I would like to know if

- The [XPathNSResolver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XPathNSResolver) could be created such that the namespace declarations in the root, as well as all child elements, are accounted for. OR
- The xmlns: declarations could be hoisted to the root.

Alternate solutions are also welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a function to achieve the second approach. However, even after applying the function xmlObj still can't be used directly for the given XPath. The xmlObj needs to be deserialised and re-serialized (see lines 41 & 42 in the snippet) for the XPath to be evaluated successfully.

```js
function hoistNameSpaceAttributesToRoot(DOMNode) {
 if (DOMNode instanceof Element) {
  if (DOMNode.hasAttributes() && DOMNode !== DOMNode.ownerDocument.documentElement) {
   const attrs = DOMNode.attributes;
   for (let i = attrs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (attrs[i].name.startsWith('xmlns:')) {
     DOMNode.ownerDocument.documentElement.setAttribute(attrs[i].name, attrs[i].value);
     DOMNode.removeAttribute(attrs[i].name);
    }
   }
   if (DOMNode.hasAttribute('xmlns')) {
    DOMNode.removeAttribute('xmlns');
   }
  }
 }
 // First check that the element has child nodes
 if (DOMNode.hasChildNodes()) {
  const children = DOMNode.childNodes;

  // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-for-of
  for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
   // do something with each child as children[i]
   // NOTE: List is live, adding or removing children will change the list
   this.hoistNameSpaceAttributesToRoot(children[i]);
  }
 }
}
let xmlStr = `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:n0="http://tempuri.org/">
    <soapenv:Header>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <n0:SavePartnerDetailsWithToken xmlns:n2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
            <n0:userToken></n0:userToken>
            <n2:myNode>valueHere</n2:myNode>
        </n0:SavePartnerDetailsWithToken>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`;
let xmlObj = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlStr, 'application/xml');
hoistNameSpaceAttributesToRoot(xmlObj);
xmlStr = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlObj);
xmlObj = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlStr, 'application/xml');
const nsResolver = xmlObj.createNSResolver(xmlObj.ownerDocument === null ? xmlObj.documentElement : xmlObj.ownerDocument.documentElement);
const firstNode = xmlObj.evaluate('/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/n0:SavePartnerDetailsWithToken/n2:myNode', xmlObj, nsResolver, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
console.log(firstNode.singleNodeValue.textContent)
```